# How to programatically calibrate Turningy esc?

Tags: c, calibration, esc, avr

I have a [Turnigy ESC](https://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__14630__Turnigy_TrackStar_18A_1_18th_Scale_Brushless_Car_ESC_.html) and I am controlling it from AVR. Now I need to calibrate it to set the range of the input.
With a servo tester I managed to calibrate it without any problems, more or less by following the user guide, but when I try to do the same procedure from code, the ESC starts beeping in some confused pattern and then enters programming mode.

My code looks like this:

```
void calibrate_turningy_esc()
{
    servo_set16(SERVO_RANGE_TICKS);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        _delay_ms(1);
    servo_set16(-SERVO_RANGE_TICKS);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        _delay_ms(1);
    servo_set16(0);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        _delay_ms(1);
}
```

where +SERVO_RANGE_TICKS is 2.2ms pulse length, -SERVO_RANGE_TICKS is 0.8ms pulse length and 0 is 1.5ms. The timeouts of 10s were measured during the manual calibration with a stopwatch.

<strike>I have checked with an oscilloscope that the output servo signal looks the way I would expect it -- 10 seconds of 2.2ms pulses, 10 seconds of 0.8ms pulses and then 1.5ms pulses.</strike>
Edit: I made a mistake here, see my answer.

Do you have any idea what to change to calibrate the ESC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the calibration code was essentially correct. The problem was in my Makefile dependency code.

For previous tests i used a range from 0.5 to 2.5ms and that was clearly too much for this ESC. I tried to decrease the range to 0.8ms - 2.2ms, but my makefile didn't notice the change and kept uploading the old version ... After a clean rebuild the ESC is calibrated without any problems.

As for the oscilloscope check... I mixed them up :-)